# What does "happens to" means in this context?

Tags: american-english, british-english

Sometimes people say like "and he happens to be my bestfriend" he could have instead he "and he is my bestfriend"

I'm trying to understand what's the difference when someone uses "happens to"

Comment: Related: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/109269/what-does-the-phrase-happen-to-be-mean

Comment: "and he happens to be my best friend" = "and **coincidentally** he is my best friend" or "and, **by chance** or **luckily** he is my best friend." == Note that "best friend" is 2 words.

Comment: "and he _happens to be my bestfriend_"  (with the stress shown) can be used to mean "and he's my bestfriend – don't treat that fact lightly!"